# JQuery 1.6.2 AJAX Vulnerable XSS

Tags: jquery, xss

Recently, a very old project of the company was scanned and found to have XSS security issues.
The code is probably like this：

```
$.ajax({

    url: xxx,
    type: "POST", cache: false, processData: false, dataType: "xml",typeId:arrReqPam[j][0] ,
    success: function(**xmlDoc**){
        $(**xmlDoc**).find("r").each(function(i){
            arrFirmMemb2.push({txt:this.getAttribute("n"), id:this.getAttribute("i")});
        });
}});
```

and it prompted me that the returned object **xmlDoc** is not safe.

What do I need to do to make it safe?

Comment: And in order to be compatible with IE7, we do not plan to upgrade JQuery to 2.x

Comment: Look to a version that fixed it, and see if you can patch your version locally. That is one of the problems of maintaining support to old/obsolete software, keeping backwards compatibility also keeps old/bad security issues. Maybe it was fixed in a version before 2.x that could be used instead?